# ADO Recordset eof is always true even though there is data

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, ado

Below is a piece of code which runs a stored procedure and returns 1 row.

If I run the below piece of code EOF returns true in some cases, even when I know there is data. Sometimes it works correctly sometimes not.

```
set objConn = server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.open funcReadIntranetConnection
set rs = objConn.execute(strSql)


if not rs.eof then

else

end if
```

I am running those code twice after each other, not sure if that is related, but I recreate all the connections etc each time.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you specifying `On Error Resume Next` anywhere? It may be plowing through any errors and even through your `If` test.

Comment: "Sometimes it works correctly sometimes not" - nobody else but you is able to determine the conditions for success and failure.

Comment: You don't even specify what your `strSql` contains, so how are we supposed to know whether it will return an open resultset or not?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest:

```
Do while not rs.eof
'your code here
Loop
```

Comment: I'd make that `Do Until rs.eof`, because it's closer to natural language.

Comment: Neither this answer or the comment above addresses the problem. The issue is whether the SQL is returning a valid resultset or not, the OP already knows how to check `EOF`. How do you know they don't want to use `GetRows()` to output to an Array? An `If` in this context is perfectly valid.